# Multiplication rule in combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say there are 9 cards with digits from 0-8. Two cards are randomly selected and placed next to one another so that the second card is placed on the right. What is the probability that the number formed by these cards is even.

On the one hand, if it doesn't matter which card is placed where, there are 5 suitable cards for the first choice and then 8 cards for the remaining card. In total, 40 combinations.
 In this case, does the placement of cards matter?
We can select any of the 9 cards for the left digit, but then the set of available options for the second cards is dependent on what we selected first.

Is it correct, that the multiplication rule in combinatorics is only applicable for disjoint sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) is valid for disjoint sets, if we consider a scenario where replacement is allowed. For instance, there are $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ ways to select two items from $\{A, B, C\}$, if $(A, A)$ is a valid option. In your case, the selected card is not replaced, so this rule does not apply. One way to look at the above is indeed by considering first an even card for the right and then any card for the left, resulting in a probability of:

$$\frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{8}{8} = \frac{5}{9}$$

Alternatively, you could consider two cases: one in which the first card is even and one in which the first card is odd. Of course, the result of the first card affects the probability of the result of the second. In this case, we find:

$$\frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8} + \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{8} = \frac{40}{72} = \frac{5}{9}$$